# RadMaskedTextBox Error after upgrade from Silverlight 4 to Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight

I've got the following error message after upgrading from Silverlight 4 to Silverlight 5

> The type or namespace name 'RadMaskedTextBox' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

RadMaskedTextBox not exists anymore, you must use the RadMaskedInput class now.

More info in [Telerik's site](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radmaskedinput/overview).